# How do I forward mails from Outlook 2007 at office to my personal Email ID like gmail

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007

I would like to know is there is any way that I can forward my Officials Mails from Outlook to my personal ID like Gmail or another ?

I would like to do this to keep a track of my official mails when am on leave and not accessing Office network .

Answer (score 1):

Not too complicated at all, actually -- you can set up rules in order to filter and perform operations on incoming mail. Microsoft [has a primer on rules](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/HA010173281033.aspx) that would be good to read up on. I don't have Outlook in front of me, but I believe you can get to the rules interface under the Tools (or maybe Options?) menu.

I believe you can even set up a rule that only gets enabled if you mark yourself out-of-office. It's been quite a long time since I've used the out-of-office functionality in Outlook, but I suspect that would be a good idea so you don't forward every email when you're still at the office. At the very least, you can enable/disable rules manually.

One note of warning: doing something like this may be dangerous if your employer considers email to contain sensitive information. Best to check with your operations/IT department lest you get into trouble for forwarding emails outside the company. Also, worth checking with IT to see if you have an external webmail interface, which many companies do, specifically for the occasions when employees want to check their email away from the office.

Good luck!